# Make with header files in another directories

Tags: makefile, webrtc

Is it possible to build program with header files in another directories using makefile?
For example, I have some file (named client.cc), that contain:

```
...
#include "talk/examples/peerconnection/client/conductor.h"
#include "talk/examples/peerconnection/client/main_wnd.h"
...
```

This includes are in another directory. How I can add it to my makefile?
At this moment, I have Makefile, that contain:

```
CXX=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
INC=-I/home/footniko/my/webrtcnative/trunk/
TARGET=$(shell basename `pwd`)
SOURCES=$(wildcard *.cc)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:%.cc=%.o)

all: $(TARGET)

$(OBJECTS): $(SOURCES)

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) -o $(TARGET) $(LDFLAGS) $(INC) $(OBJECTS) $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(TARGET)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Where `/home/footniko/my/webrtcnative/trunk/` - is an absolute path to my headers. But when I'm trying to make, have this error:

```
client.cc:28:59: fatal error: talk/examples/peerconnection/client/conductor.h: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add that directory through `CPPFLAGS` which will be passed to the preprocessor,

```
CPPFLAGS = -I/home/footniko/my/webrtcnative/trunk/
```

Comment: `include`s are handled by the preprocessor, should probably be `CPPFLAGS`.

Comment: @user657267 Yes, `CPPFLAGS` works for about everything. But the OP is doing C++, so I just wanted to be more specific.

Comment: If you want to be specific you should use `CPPFLAGS`, because that is the correct variable for preprocessor flags. `CXXFLAGS` is used to pass flags to the c++ *compiler*, not the preprocessor. Sure it isn't going to make any difference at all here but it's a good habit to get into in case you have a project that uses different languages and relies on implicit rules, or to avoid confusion for other people reading your Makefile who expect the built-in variables to be used correctly.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I had a twisted understanding there. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. That works, however I have another errors with webrtc, but it is another question...